# PHP if statements with sessions (login&register)

Tags: php, session

I currently have two code elements on my website.

I'm looking to have both show up (not at the same time) through the use of whether someone is logged in.

I currently have:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
    {
      include 'profile-stats.php'; // 45x45 profile picture w/ name and notifications
    } else {
      include 'log-reg.php'; // Login and register links
    };
?>
```

Would this work? I'm unsure...
Could I have two IF statements with a condition, and link them?

IF 1: `(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))`

IF 2: `(!isset($_SESSION['login_user']))`

Edit:

Logout.php

```
<?php
   session_start();

   if(session_destroy()) {
      header("Location: home.php"); // This is the page that has the above IF statement.
   }
?>
```

The IF Statement is in the header.php file. Which is called on all pages (except session.php,config.php, and others) It's actually in the header of every page. So would that affect it?

Comment: It depends on how you logout the user. If it's still set after logout then no it won't work as expected.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: There's no need to have both conditions, it's either set else it's not. What you posted as the code, will suffice.

Comment: after your edit: you shouldn't redirect but include the 'home.php' (and maybe rename it to something like 'logincheck'). Other than that: all good. Any problems?? _wait_: why do you destroy the session?

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! Many thanks.

Comment: @AlisterBulman I did. However, I was trying to ask if that it was best to have that. OR two IF statements (or to include both statements)

Answer (score 0):

#### Here is a preferred version of your codes.

```
<?php
    //use empty() it checks for ( null | empty | false ) isset only check for empty.
    if( empty($_SESSION['login_user']) )
    {
        // Check for error first before running your codes.
        header("Location: log-reg.php"); 
        //Always kill the script after redirect.
        exit();
    }
    
    //if you passed error checking then load profile
    include 'profile-stats.php'; // 45x45 profile picture w/ name and notifications
?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php
//Start session once, not everytime unless session is empty.
if( session_id() == '' )
{
   session_start();
}

   // Store user status as true or false if logged in.
   $loggedIn = ( !empty( $_SESSION['login_user'] ) ) ? true : false ;
   
   // Check if user is currently logged in and destroy all sessions if true,
   // Else do nothing;
   if( !$loggedIn )
   {
       //session destroy session.
       session_destroy();
       header("Location: home.php");
       exit();
   }
?>
```

Hope it helps!